# Take parameter, determine if its an object or list<>; if list<> then loop and treat each item as object

Tags: c#, list, generics, casting

Aim

Take an object or list<>.

If it's an object then do something with it (done).

If it's a list<> (any type of list<>) then loop through each item, and do similar thing as object to each item, returning a dictionary or array (return type not important at the moment).

What I have so far, the object bit...

```
  public static Dictionary<string, object> Pick (object obj, Array Picklist) {
    Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object> ();
    foreach (string key in Picklist) {
      dic.Add(key, obj.GetType ().GetProperty (key).GetValue (obj, null));
    }
    return dic;
  }
```

So next I need to determine if it's an object or a list<>, I've tried all sorts of generics, the biggest problem I've come across is casting it into a list<> of unknown type.

Any way of doing it or understanding the right steps, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use a list of length 1 to represent a single object.

Comment: What about just a plain old `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Can you give me a simple example? I've shut my windows vm (for now).

Comment: And why would you want to do this in preference to providing two overloads, one for `IEnumerable<string>` and one for a single `string`? The second could then call the first.

Comment: Protip: Keep your dev environment open during the first few minutes after asking a question.

Comment: @Jon A param of IEnumberable<object>, I assume you mean? I could do that, I guess, but interested to know if there is another way, but i guess that would the simpler way.

Comment: Is list<> always going to be List<string> ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - yeah I know, sorry got bored of playing with CS; openned the stackoverflow question as the windows was running some updates (always with the updates).

Comment: @Duncan: Ah sorry, I thought we were talking about the second parameter. But the concept still stands -- one overload for `object obj` and one for `IEnumerable collection`. This way it is obvious to the user of the code that you can operate either on a single object or on a collection.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> Pick(object obj, Array Picklist) 
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object> ();
    IEnumerable items = obj as IEnumerable ?? new[] { obj };
    foreach(string key in Picklist) 
    {
        foreach(object item in items)
        {
            dic.Add(key, item.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(item, null));
        }
    }

    return dic;
}
```

Note however, this will fail if you actually try to provide two or more items, since it will attempt to add the same key to the dictionary twice. It will also fail if you try to pass an object which doesn't have one of the specified properties. It's unclear exactly what you want this method to do in these cases, but this code seems to be just an example, so you'll have to figure that detail out in your real code.

Comment: Why use both `is` and `as` in the same expression? just use `as` and possibly the ?? operator

Comment: @JaredPar Excellent suggestion. That does make it a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, `List<T>` is both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` (meaning its contents can be enumerated as instances of `object`). You can use `IEnumerable` with link like this:

```
object o = new List<string>() ;
...
((IEnumerable)o).Cast<object>().DoSomethingLinqy( x => ... ) ;
```

If you're only interested in differentiating between `List<T>` (and not its subtypes) and any other class (including subtypes of `List<T>`), then this code should do you:

```
object o = GetSomeObject() ;
bool isGenericList = o.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>) ;
```

If you need to treat `List<T>` and its subtypes the same, then you'll need something list this:

```
static bool IsInstanceOfGenericType( object o, Type genericType )
{
    bool isGenericTypeInstance = false ;
    for ( Type t = o.GetType() ; t != null && !isGenericTypeInstance ; t = t.BaseType )
    {
      isGenericTypeInstance =  t.IsGenericType
                            && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType
                            ;
    }
    return isGenericType ;
}
```

Which you'd use thusly:

```
object o = GetSomeObject() ;
bool isGenericList = isInstanceOfGenericType( o , typeof(List<>) ) ;
```

If you need to be able to identify objects as implementing a generic interface, then the level of complexity goes up. The above function need to be modified such that as it runs up the inheritance hierachy, it not only checks the type, but also checks each interface implemented by the type (using `Type.GetInterfaces()`) in a way similar to the way the type check is done.